# EXCEL ExportAsFixedFormat to save some sheets

Tags: excel, vba, file, save

Good morning,

```
Sub pdfs()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim i As Integer
Dim nome_arquivo As String
For i = 5 To Sheets.Count
nome_arquivo = Sheets(i).Name


With Sheets(i)
.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & nome_arquivo & ".xlsx"

End With

Next i

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

How can I adapt to create Excel files (.xlsx) instead of pdf files?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.copy -> second example

Comment: Perfect! Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I found this vba code to create excel files from sheet 5:

```
 Sub excels()

 Dim i As Integer
 Dim name1 As String
 For i = 5 To Sheets.Count
 name1= Sheets(i).Name

 Worksheets(i).Copy

  With ActiveWorkbook
 .SaveAs Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & name1 & ".xlsx", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook
  .Close SaveChanges:=False
  End With
  Next i

  End Sub
```